# Making record fields case sensitive in PotgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, postgresql-9.3

I am having problems defining the record's fields as case sensitive in my PostgreSQL stored procedure. I define my record as:

```
CREATE TYPE  json_record AS (
    "objectType" text ,
    "objectSubtype" text 
};
```

The reason why I need the the fields to be case sensitive is because the record is populated from JSON in stored procedure and I have no control over JSON content

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION record(id uuid, json_in json)  RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
   raw_record json_record;
BEGIN
   SELECT  json_populate_record( NULL::json_record, json_in) INTO raw_record;
   INSERT INTO my_resource (uuid, type, subtype) 
      SELECT (id, raw_record.objectType, raw_record.objectSubtype);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

When I execute the procedure I am getting the error:

```
ERROR:  record "raw_record" has no field "objecttype"
```

I understand the cause of the error: the "json_record" is defined with the case sensitive fields, but PostgreSQL's execution engine converted raw_record.objectType and  raw_record.objectSubtype to raw_record.objecttype and  raw_record.objectsubtype. The question is how to avoid this situation  and force record's fields to be treated as case sensitive. The only solution I can think of is to use dynamic SQL, build the query piece by piece and wrap the fields in quote_ident(), but I am wondering if there a simpler solution to enforce case sensitivity for a record?

Answer (score 0):

> *force record's fields to be treated as case sensitive*

The same way you always use case-sensitive identifiers: you need to enclose them in double quotes. You also don't really need a `SELECT` clause for the insert:

```
INSERT INTO my_resource (uuid, type, subtype) 
VALUES (id, raw_record."objectType", raw_record."objectSubtype");
```

---

As a side note: `select (a,b,c)` does **not** what you think it does. It selects a **single** column that is an anonymous record (with three fields). It does not select three columns. So if you do want to stick with the `select` version instead of `values`, you have to remove the parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO my_resource (uuid, type, subtype) 
SELECT id, raw_record."objectType", raw_record."objectSubtype";
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_nameThank you very much. I did not realize that I can double quote that way. You suggestion solved my problem